# AWS CodeDeploy: Service role Cannot assume role provided

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to setup CodeDeploy with my GitHub and I've found some issue.

I've created `service role` as mentioned in documentation with `AWSCodeDeployRole` policy.

During my Code Deploy Application creation process I've got an issue:

```
Cannot assume role provided.
```

As I can see, my role with `AWSCodeDeployRole` have a lot of autoscaling permissions, but it's not expected for me:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "autoscaling:CompleteLifecycleAction",
        "autoscaling:DeleteLifecycleHook",
        "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
        "autoscaling:DescribeLifecycleHooks",
        "autoscaling:PutLifecycleHook",
        "autoscaling:RecordLifecycleActionHeartbeat",
        "autoscaling:CreateAutoScalingGroup",
        "autoscaling:UpdateAutoScalingGroup",
        "autoscaling:EnableMetricsCollection",
        "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
        "autoscaling:DescribePolicies",
        "autoscaling:DescribeScheduledActions",
        "autoscaling:DescribeNotificationConfigurations",
        "autoscaling:DescribeLifecycleHooks",
        "autoscaling:SuspendProcesses",
        "autoscaling:ResumeProcesses",
        "autoscaling:AttachLoadBalancers",
        "autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy",
        "autoscaling:PutScheduledUpdateGroupAction",
        "autoscaling:PutNotificationConfiguration",
        "autoscaling:PutLifecycleHook",
        "autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities",
        "autoscaling:DeleteAutoScalingGroup",
        "ec2:DescribeInstances",
        "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
        "ec2:TerminateInstances",
        "tag:GetTags",
        "tag:GetResources",
        "sns:Publish",
        "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
        "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
        "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeInstanceHealth",
        "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer",
        "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

During some googling, I've found that CodeDeploy application may expect something similar to:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "codedeploy.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I'm trying to create this policy manually it also fails with error:

```
This policy contains the following error: Has prohibited field Principal For more information about the IAM policy grammar, see AWS IAM Policies.
```

So, what is the expected service role for `Code Deploy Application`?

Btw, Code deploy is running on my EC2 instance.

Comment: I believe you're confusing the permissions policy with the [trust relationships policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_manage_modify.html).  They're both policies, with similar syntax, but their purposes are different: the former specifies what actions the role allows or denies (e.g. the autoscaling actions) and the latter specifies which entities (principals) can assume the role (e.g. the `codedeploy.amazonaws.com` service principal).

Comment: Well, Trust relationships for my `Service role` looks like: `{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: Do you see the similarity between this and the policy you found during your googling?  `codedeploy` vs. `ec2`?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you may post your suggestion and I'll approve it. Previously removing my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, according to @Michael comment, I've found some differences in my `Trust relationships policy` for `Service role`.

It looks like default `AWSCodeDeployRole` can't handle it properly for Code Deploy.

To fix this issue I've replaced `"Service": [
"ec2.amazonaws.com"]` with `"Service": [
"codedeploy.amazonaws.com"]`

And it works!

Comment: Nice find mate should be a default!

Answer (score 2):

For those that find this via Google - in my Cloud Formation templates, I formatted the ARN wrong, and the error wasn't descriptive:

Roles need to be specified this way:
`arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/CodeDeployRole` NOTE `:role/` and not `:instance-profile/`

The error is exactly as above that it can't assume the role, though it's because you specified it wrong.

Comment: I recommend to you to not share private data like instance IDs or account IDs

Comment: It's not real - 1234567890

Answer (score 0):

I was following the tutorial but it didn't mention you have to edit the Trust Relationship for the service role. I got the same error as mentioned until I changed the below.

I changed

```
        "Service": "codebuild.amazonaws.com"
```

To

```
"Service" : [
      "codedeploy.amazonaws.com",
      "codebuild.amazonaws.com"
    ]
```